# KeyError string in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[image]    us_permit["Population estimates, July 1, 2016, (V2016)"]
I have a dataframe that has a very long string column, but whenever I select those columns, it returns an error

```
KeyError: 'Population estimates, July 1, 2016, (V2016)'
```

why is that?

Comment: what is the output of `print(us_permit.columns)` ? Any unexpected whitespace around the names?

Comment: That's not the correct column name. Probably the spaces or punctuation are wrong. Using column names like that seems like a poor idea.

Comment: I uploaded the photo to see the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
census_2016_df = census_df[[0,1]]
```

This will give you state and Population estimates, July 1, 2016, (V2016) on your table.

Answer (score 0):

`df.columns` or `df.keys()` return array of columns that on dataframe. you can print or just call using the index. for example `df[df.columns[0]]` will return the first column of the dataframe

or if you want to get the first and second columns as dataframe, you can use `df[[df.columns[0],df.columns[1]]]`. that will return dataframe with first and second column